# How expand flexbox to padding in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

how do i put that flexbox on all that blue background

I attach a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Here Code with Tailwind-CSS:

```html
<!-- Tailwind + Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css”>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<header class="bg-blue-default flex justify-between p-3.5 text-xs m-0">
  <div class="flex justify-between text-white-grayed">
    <a class="pl-4 pr-4 hover:text-white-default border-r border-white-default" href="">info@example.eu</a>
    <a class="hover:text-white-default" href="">+000 000 000 000</a>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Your header is a flexbox already and takes the full width. Your first child (`div`) however only takes as much space as it needs. You need to add `w-full` which makes the `div` take up all the available width and justifies its items inside respecting the entire width.

```html
<!-- Tailwind + Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css”>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<header class="bg-blue-default flex justify-between p-3.5 text-xs m-0">
  <div class="w-full flex justify-between items-center text-white-grayed">
    <a class="pl-4 pr-4 hover:text-white-default border-r border-white-default" href="">info@example.eu</a>
    <a class="hover:text-white-default" href="">+000 000 000 000</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If I used your code this has happened and still flexbox is not across the backgroung IMG:https://ctrlv.sk/qMiU

Comment: Looks like you want to `center` all items vertically. This can be done by adding `.items-center` to your flexbox. Edited the answer. You really need to provide a better explanation on what you want along with proper sample code. It's very difficult to understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: I need those white lines across the blue background and the phone to be in one line on how to do it IMG:https://ctrlv.sk/W8SH

Comment: Provide the full code to it, otherwise it's nearly impossible to understand what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Only remove `flex` class from header

use this

```
<header class="bg-blue-default justify-between p-3.5 text-xs m-0">
```

instead of

```
<header class="bg-blue-default flex justify-between p-3.5 text-xs m-0">
```

Comment: If I used your code this has happened and still flexbox is not across the backgroung IMG:https://ctrlv.sk/IAhw